# Does Hibernate alter table itself?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Hibernate altering database table Automatically by adding new columns

I am pointing to stored proc from my JPA entity. The mapping in @TAble has been done to a random table used in Stored proc . Now The entity contains some fields used by stored proc but not present in Table define in @Table .

Will this Alter the table to add the new column in database ?

Comment: it depends on the `hibernate.ddl-auto` hibernate property. please see this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) for more info.

Comment: How is this config read. Is it read by the framework itself or we need to read it via code.

Comment: depends of you project structure. are you using spring ? spring data? a maven project ? do you have an application.properties/yml file ?

Comment: or are you using annotations configurations ?

Comment: and finally, what is your need ? what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: What's happening is that we have some code running which points to sqlserver.  When we run the test cases , it points to h2 db .. but for further testing we point test classes to point to real databases by making changes in test.properties files. These property files are loaded from a test class.
These property files have the hibernate.ddl-auto = update . Now will this property be read from file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently hbm2ddl.auto=update only creates new columns. 
It doesn't alter or drop columns. This can be done fairly easily - just compare the entity model to the database metadata.

Comment: How is this config read. is it read by the framework itself or we need to read it via code.

Comment: Hibernate framework will use the hibernate.cfg.xml file using sessionFactory and StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.